# Python escape character

Tags: python, path, escaping

I've struggled for hours with this and although I found a solution, I don't like it.
Is there a built in way to solve this:

You are on Windows with a variable containing a path.
You are trying to open a file with it, but it contains escape characters that you can't determine until runtime.

If you use 'shutil' and do:
`shutil.copy(file_path, new_file_path)`

It works fine.

But if you try and use the same path with:

`f = open(file_path, encoding="utf8")`

It doesn't work because the '\a' in the path is read as a 'Bell' = 7

I tried doing all of these, but the only thing I've gotten to work is the custom function 'reconstruct_broken_string'.

```
    file_path = "F:\ScriptsFilePath\addons\import_test.py"

    print(sys.getdefaultencoding())
    print()
    print(file_path.replace('\\', r'\\'))
    print( '%r' % (file_path))
    print( r'r"' + "'" + file_path+ "'")
    print(file_path.encode('unicode-escape'))
    print(os.path.normpath(file_path))
    print(repr(file_path))

    print()
    print(reconstruct_broken_string(file_path))


backslash_map = { '\a': r'\a', '\b': r'\b', '\f': r'\f',
                  '\n': r'\n', '\r': r'\r', '\t': r'\t', '\v': r'\v' }
def reconstruct_broken_string(s):
    for key, value in backslash_map.items():
        s = s.replace(key, value)
    return s
```

Here is the printout:

```
utf-8

F:\\ScriptsFilePathddons\\import_test.py
'F:\\ScriptsFilePath\x07ddons\\import_test.py'
r"'F:\ScriptsFilePathddons\import_test.py'
b'F:\\\\ScriptsFilePath\\x07ddons\\\\import_test.py'
F:\ScriptsFilePathddons\import_test.py
'F:\\ScriptsFilePath\x07ddons\\import_test.py'

F:\ScriptsFilePath\addons\import_test.py
```

Is there a built in way to do this rather than this function?
Why does it work with 'shutil' and not 'open'

Thanks

Comment: Please reduce your program to the smallest possible *complete* program that demonstrates the error. Then copy-paste that short program into your question. See http://SSCCE.ORG for information about this debugging technique.

Comment: You can simplify the `reconstruct_broken_string` using a unique call to `str.translate`(if you are on python3). Simply change the `backslash_map` so that the keys are the *code-points*(i.e. `ord('\a'): r'\a'`) and call `file_path.translate(backslash_map)`.

Comment: I tried this to no avail: backslash_map = {ord('\a') : r'\a'} then: 
    file_path.translate(backslash_map)

Comment: Let's try this from another angle. You say that `open()` "doesn't work." Can you expand on that? What does `open()` return? Does it raise an exception? If so, can you copy-paste the precise error message?

Comment: 'Open' can't find the file because the '\a' in the path is treated as an escape character (bell, which is 7).  Why is 'Open' even looking for escape characters in a path passed to it.  The same path in a variable passed to 'Shutil' to copy the file works fine.  'Shutil' is smart enough not to look for escape characters in a path, why isn't 'Open' smart enough to do that?

Comment: What is the precise observation that leads you to the conclusion that `open` fails because of the `\a`?

Answer (score 15):

Your problem is on this line:

```
file_path = "F:\ScriptsFilePath\addons\import_test.py"
```

Try one of these:

```
file_path = r"F:\ScriptsFilePath\addons\import_test.py"
file_path = "F:\\ScriptsFilePath\\addons\\import_test.py"
```

Or even:

```
file_path = "F:/ScriptsFilePath/addons/import_test.py"
```

(Yes, Windows accept forward slash as a file separator.)

Ref: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals

Comment: Or use forward slashes. Specifically, it's the `\a` escape.

Comment: Yes but the path is in a variable I get at runtime and I can't add 'r' in the front of a variable name.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code that initializes that variable.

Comment: The code that initializes the variable is the return value from a file browser window.  I have no control over it.

Comment: What graphics toolkit are you using? Can you provide a trivially small program that uses the toolkit and reproduces the error?

Answer (score 0):

If the path is in a variable, just replace all '\' with '/' using any of Python's string manipulation functions. It should solve the problem.

Comment: How? I tried file_path.replace('\\','/') you have to double up the escape character or it won't run, and it prints out as: F:\ScriptsFilePathddons\import_test.py

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified version demonstrating how 'repr' doesn't work correctly.

```
file_path = "F:\tab\a_bell\newline.py"
print(file_path)
print(repr(file_path))
```

This prints:

```
F:  ab_bell
ewline.py

and

F:\tab\x07_bell\newline.py'
```

As you can see 'repr' works with escape-tab, escape-newline, etc., but it doesn't work with '\a' which is escape bell.

Is this is bug in 'repr'?
Is there a built in solution to this problem that doesn't require programmers to write a custom function like the 'reconstruct_broken_string(s)'?
If not, how can python be this lame?

Comment: Again, the problem with *this* program is the line `file_path = "F:\tab\a_bell\newline.py"`. That string literal has a tab, a bell, and a newline in it. If you want their to be slashes in the string, you must escape them `'\\'` or use a raw string `r'f:\tab ...'`. But I suspect that isn't the problem with your real program, since you've said elsewhere that you don'thave an assignment statement.

Comment: `repr` is in this program is working perfectly. `repr()` returns a string which, if passed to `eval()` would produce the original value.

Comment: Look at my test example here: file_path = "F:\tab\a_bell\newline.py" the '\t' in tab gets processed properly by repr, the '\n' gets processed properly, but the '\a' does not.  Why does repr not correct for all escape characters in a string?

Comment: The output of `repr` is correct. `\t` is a tab character, `\n` is a newline, `\x07` is an alert character. But, why do you care? What are you using `repr()` to do? I can hardly imagine any situation in which you might legitimately use the repr() function in your program.

Comment: If you look above, I tried many things to solve the problem of 'Open' treating backslashes in a path as an escape.  I have googled this and countless people have had the same problem, but I haven't found a single 'solved' despite all the people who have had similar problems.  The problem is really very simple:  Why is 'Open' treating backslashes as an escape when it should only be looking at a string passed to it as a path.  There is never an escape in a path! You can put an 'r' for raw in front of a hard coded string, but you can't do that in front of a variable as far as I know.

Comment: `open` **isn't** treating backslashes as an escape. There are no backslashes in the string in this example. There is a tab, a newline and an alert, but there are no backslashes. If you want backslashes to be in your string, you have to put them there when you construct the string.

Comment: Rob, this problem is really very simple, it has come up time and time again in various coding forums.  You haven't made a single constructive comment about it.  Either you have a solution to the problem of being handed a string that you have no control over and processing it in a way that corrects for '\' path characters or you don't.  If you don't that is fine, but why do you keep commenting here without offering solutions?

Comment: You even comment that: " I can hardly imagine any situation in which you might legitimately use the repr() function in your program" when I have showed you that it corrects for '\t' and '\n' in a string.  Many people have recommended it for this very purpose.  It just doesn't correct for '\a'.  Now either you have a built in python solution or you don't.  I already offered a custom function to solve the problem, but it is hard to believe that python doesn't have a built in solution to what is a common problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced same exact problem - tried `path = 'C:\temp\importfile.xlsx'` and kept getting an error `"No such file or directory: 'C:\\Temp\\importdata.xlsx'"`.  I used forward slashes instead and my import worked.  Have you tried `file_path = "F:/ScriptsFilePath/addons/import_test.py"`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an r in front of a string so that Python handles it as a raw string-

```
filePath = input()
try:
    print(filePath)
except:
    print(r""+filePath)
```

Comment: but you can't do that for a var.