# How would I make this work? \n in a filepath (not intentional)

Tags: python

I have to read and write with `f=open` etc

When using this my file path is:

```
f=open("N:\gcse_computing_my_name\component_2\neatest\Login.txt")(w)
```

using \N or \n in this file path breaks my code. I can't change the folder name and have to use that folder.

How would I get around this?

Comment: Try """N:\gcse_computing_my_name\component_2\neatest\Login.txt""" which should be the raw string

Comment: Escape it with doubleslash \\

Comment: @pazqo, eh? Triple quotes don't make something a raw string, `r'...'` syntax does. `"""foo"""` is not raw, `r"""foo"""` is.

Comment: @EricDuminil, `"""\n"""` is a string that contains one character, not two. So that's not what the OP needs. A "raw" string in Python is indeed one that doesn't have escape sequences interpreted, which (again) is what they need.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you are completely right! I should have took 10 seconds to check in console :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Thanks for the explanation, you're right. `"""\g"""` outputs `'\\g'`, but it doesn't work with `\n`.

Comment: @EricDuminil, right -- if an escape sequence doesn't exist in Python, it just gets ignored. There is no `\g` sequence, so it's not a good one to test with. (I'm tempted to call this a design flaw in the language, but too late to fix it now).

Comment: @SamFurness, ...btw, see the related question [Why do backslashes appear twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085680/why-do-backslashes-appear-twice), which provides more context for the behavior at hand.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I didn't specifically test `\g`. But by typing `"""N:\gcse_computing_my_name\component_2\neatest\Login.txt""‌​"`, I noticed that some backslashes were escaped, so I assumed they all were.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python escape character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18682695/python-escape-character)

Comment: @William, I really expect there to *be* a good dupe for this one somewhere, but I'm not convinced that's it. The OP there is asking how to patch up a mangled path, not how to enter it in such a way as to avoid mangling in the first place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\n` is an escape sequence to Python, telling it to replace that with a single newline.

`\\` is another escape sequence, which is replaced with a single backslash literal.

You also have the option to turn off interpretation of escape sequences entirely by using "raw string" syntax. Thus, your options:

- A raw string

  ```
  f = open(r'N:\gcse_computing_my_name\component_2\neatest\Login.txt', 'w')
  ```
- Doubling up your backslashes

  ```
  f = open('N:\\gcse_computing_my_name\\component_2\\neatest\\Login.txt', 'w')
  ```
- Using forward slashes instead (not allowed everywhere on Windows, but perfectly acceptable in Python):

  ```
  f = open('N:/gcse_computing_my_name/component_2/neatest/Login.txt', 'w')
  ```

Comment: it is very common on windows systems to use the double backslash form for file paths. alternately, python's `open` and most `os.path` functions will automatically interpret forward slashes correctly for windows: `open("N:/gcse_computing_my_name/component_2/neatest/Login.txt")`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `my_var.replace('\n', '')` which removed the new line character and resolved the issue I was experiencing. As a result, the code is now functioning as expected.