# Python folder path string escape character error

Tags: python, path, directory, backslash

I am trying to iterate through a directory and I copied its file path from right clicking it.

It gives an escape character error. How do I present the folder address so It works?

```
folder_dir = "C:\Users\geniu\OneDrive\GW\Spring 2024\CSCI 6527\test_images"
```

Error:

> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 1-2: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: add `r` before the string. so it's `folder_dir = r"C:\Users\geniu\OneDrive\GW\Spring 2024\CSCI 6527\test_images"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python escape character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18682695/python-escape-character)